# Hibernate - New colums from a joined table

Tags: sql, hibernate, mapping

I have a class User object. I am trying to load this object from the Database using Hibernate.
My SQL statement is:

```
SELECT
    users.uid               AS uid,
    users.deleted           AS deleted,
    users.username          AS username,
    users.passwd            AS passwd,
    users.disabled          AS disabled,
    users.lockout           AS lockout,
    users.expires           AS expires,
    data_firstname.value            AS firstname,
    data_lastname.value     AS lastname 
FROM 
    ac_users as users
LEFT JOIN
    ac_userdef_data as data_firstname
ON
    users.uid = data_firstname.parentuid AND
    data_firstname.fieldname like 'firstname'
LEFT JOIN
    ac_userdef_data as data_lastname
ON
    users.uid = data_lastname.parentuid AND
    data_lastname.fieldname like 'lastname'
WHERE
    users.deleted = 0
```

My mapping for the User class is:

```
<class name="com.agetor.commons.security.User" table="ac_users">
    <id name="uid" column="uid" type="long" >
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="deleted" column="deleted" />
    <property name="username" column="username" />   
    <property name="password" column="passwd" />
    <property name="firstname" column="firstname" />
    <property name="lastname" column="lastname" />
    <property name="disabled" column="disabled" />
    <property name="lockout" column="lockout" />
    <property name="expires" column="expires" />            
</class>
```

My problem is that the table ac_users does not have a column 'firstname' or 'lastname'
These columns, only exist in my resultset from the SQL-join statement.
They do also not exist in the ac_userdef_data table. There i have 2 colums: fieldname and value. and 2 rows:
fieldname = 'firstname' with some value in the value column
and another row with
fieldname = 'lastname' with some value in the value column

How do i change my mapping file, so that Hibernate will understand that it needs to load the firstname and lastname column into my firstname and lastname fields on my POJO, while those columns dont actually exist on the referenced ac_users table.?

Answer (score 1):

I now have some working code. The trick was to specify a loading Query for the User class. Hibernate then validates against the return from the Query instead of the Table design.

Class mapping

```
<class name="com.agetor.commons.security.User" table="ac_users">
    <id name="uid" column="uid" type="long" >
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="deleted" column="deleted" />
    <property name="username" column="username" />   
    <property name="password" column="passwd" />
    <property name="firstname" column="firstname" />
    <property name="lastname" column="lastname" />
    <property name="disabled" column="disabled" />
    <property name="lockout" column="lockout" />
    <property name="expires" column="expires" />                 


    <loader query-ref="GetAllUsers" />
</class>
```

My Query declaration

```
<sql-query name="GetAllUsers">
  <return alias="user" class="com.agetor.commons.security.User" />
  <![CDATA[ 
    SELECT
        users.uid               AS uid,
        users.deleted           AS deleted,
        users.username          AS username,
        users.passwd            AS passwd,
        users.disabled          AS disabled,
        users.lockout           AS lockout,
        users.expires           AS expires,
        data_firstname.value    AS firstname,
        data_lastname.value     AS lastname 
    FROM 
        ac_users as users
    LEFT JOIN
        ac_userdef_data as data_firstname
    ON
        users.uid = data_firstname.parentuid AND
        data_firstname.fieldname like 'firstname'
    LEFT JOIN
        ac_userdef_data as data_lastname
    ON
        users.uid = data_lastname.parentuid AND
        data_lastname.fieldname like 'lastname'
    WHERE
        users.deleted = 0
  ]]>
</sql-query>
```

I had to use the line `<return alias="user" class="com.agetor.commons.security.User" />` so that the returned collection was typed correctly

Comment: This answer is not 100% correct. I can load data using users = (List<User>) session.getNamedQuery("GetAllUsers").list();
But i cannot use users = session.createCriteria(User.class).list();